# PHP - while mysql_fetch_array loop error?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am using this code to show the users that are administrator:

```
<?php
while($write = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE level >1"))){
    echo ''.$write['username'].'';
}
?>
```

But the page stays loading forever! What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 7):

It's an infinite loop. You're running the query over and over.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE level >1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
while($write = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $write['username'];
}
```

*Obligatory "switch to PDO/mysqli_" message here.*

Comment: Wanting someone to fill the mysql_* bit for you? There you go (;